# Possible to delete everything after a 'space' in MySQL field?

Tags: mysql, string

Let's assume I have the following field:

' name sub _blah '

I can get rid of the outside spaces with the TRIM() function but I am actually looking to remove everything after the first space (after the trim).

so:

'name sub _blah' would turn into 'name'

I know this is possible in PHP but I am trying to do on a MySQL only call. Is there a function I do not know about for this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 27, accepted):

```
select substring_index('name sub _blah',' ',1)
```

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
SUBSTRING_INDEX(str,' ', 1)
```

Or, if you still need `TRIM` as well:

```
SUBSTRING_INDEX(TRIM(str),' ', 1)
```

See e.g. [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index) for additional documentation.